# Limiting editing options in PDFs or Excel

Tags: pdf, microsoft-excel, forms

I created an application form in Excel and I want to send it to my group members now. Here the problem is they can edit it. But I don't want to allow them to edit the questions in the form while space provided for giving answers should be editable.

Could you suggest me any good software for this?

Comment: In Excel, you can lock cells for editing and put a password on them.

Comment: PDFs generated by Excel, or … any PDF? If the latter, wouldn’t it make more sense to ask about it in a different question, as possible solutions would likely work different for PDF forms and Excel forms, no?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to [lock cells in worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Lock-cells-in-a-worksheet-b2f833bd-9db5-48a4-9ec0-8e451ac27c3a) or try [Google Forms](https://www.google.com/intl/en-GB/forms/about/) to create your application form.

Comment: Want to add some example steps? :) I know it sounds simple but it'll make your answer better.